# Emphatic do-form with do as main verb

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, emphasis

It is possible to use do as an auxiliary verb to denote emphasis:

> I do like ice cream

Is it also possible to use it when do is the main verb as well? E.g.:

> I did do (it).
>
> He does do (it).
>
> I do do (it).

Are the sentences above acceptable? Do they sound unnatural?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that **yes, they are acceptable**. For example, a kid talking to his mom:

> **Parent**: Did you do your homework? 
>   **Child**: Yes I did! 
>   **Parent**: No, I don't believe you. 
>   **Child**: I **did do** it!

As Subjunctive mentions in the comments, another option is "I **really did** it!" Or you could combine the two - "I **really did do** it!" or "I **really do care** about you!"

It's used as **a reply to disbelief**. Another example for the third person.

> **Person A**: I heard that Johnny does Taekwondo! 
>   **Person B**: I don't think he does it... 
>   **Person A**: He **does do** Taekwondo! I saw him at practice with my own eyes!

As for having something like "do do," read from Stangdon's comment below:

> It's grammatically correct, but it sounds a little funny. "I don't do a lot for the company." "No, you do do a lot for the company!" We would probably try and find a better way to phrase it, like "You actually do a lot" or "You really do a lot".

I don't think that it is strange enough to say that it wouldn't be used at all, but "do do" sounds a bit funny to the ear. You can still use it, but know that there are other options.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it is acceptable when both the auxiliary and the main verb sound the same? "You do do"

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but it sounds a little funny.  "I don't do a lot for the company."  *"No, you do do a lot for the company!"*  We would probably try and find a better way to phrase it, like "You actually do a lot" or "You really do a lot".

Comment: @fdierre In addition to sounding generally strange (but correct), you should know that the phrase "[doo doo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doo-doo)" is a (infantile) phrase for poop, which makes the unusual phrasing even worse.

Comment: @stangdon an excellent example. I really wish this to be a part of some answer as many *tend to* ignore comments! +10 if it was possible! :)

Comment: @apsillers: thank you for the tip, that's a language trap I would have never noticed. :-)