# What difference does adding 'Do' to a sentence make?

Tags: grammar

*"Take part in this."*

*"Do take part in this."*

What is difference between two sentences ?

What is need of adding do ?

Comment: This is called **the emphatic do**. It's mainly used these two ways: as a way to encourage someone to do something or to put more emphasis on the action you or they are going to take. For more information on this, see this post: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78258/emphatic-do-form-with-do-as-main-verb

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Your comment would be even better as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This grammatical form is generally known as **the so-called emphatic do**. It's mainly used the following two ways: as a way to encourage someone to do something (as in your example) or to put more emphasis on the action they or you are going to take (or took if you're describing something that happened in the past). For example:

> — Do yo mind if I ask you a couple of questions?
>   — Oh, please **do** ask me any questions you want to ask.
>
> — You really saw him there?
>   — I **did** see him there. I'm not joking.

For more information on this topic, read this article or just do a general Google search on the phrase *emphatic do*: https://www.callanschool.info/en/free-english-resources/the-emphatic-do-2