# What are the differences between "does exhibit" and "exhibits"?

Tags: verbs

In a paper I am reading, the author wrote as "The problem does exhibit the property, ..."
However, I learned that exhibit is a verb, so I think that "The problem exhibits the property, ..." is correct. What is different between them?

In a similar way, I saw "do exist" instead of just "exist" many time.

Comment: In some contexts, adding the verb _do_ before the main verb serves to add emphasis. "Don't you like John?" "Yes, I _do_ like him, but he can be impatient sometimes."

Comment: This is called the emphatic do: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-emphatic-do-1690590

Comment: There's no reason that you can't use an auxiliary verb in context. "*The problem doesn't exhibit the property—*" "*No, you're wrong! The problem **does** exhibit the property.*"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emphatic do-form with do as main verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78258/emphatic-do-form-with-do-as-main-verb)